# Select all where max dense_rank() = value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code that uses dense_rank, partitioned by an ID and ordered by val2.
I want to select all the rows where the max rank for any given ID is 2.

The below code provides the correct output for initial steps.

```
Select distinct 
`account id`, `val2`, distinct_rank, observation_total
from ( Select 
`account id`, `val2`, dense_rank() 
over (partition by `account id` order by `val2` desc) as distinct_rank,
count(*) 
over (partition by `account id` order by `val2` desc) as observation_total
from TABLE1 );
```

Sample Result:

```
account id | val2 | distinct_rank 
___________________________________
1          | a    | 1
2          | a    | 1
2          | b    | 2
2          | c    | 3
3          | d    | 1
3          | e    | 2
```

So I need a query that will only select rows where the max distinct_rank per account id = 2, or some other value.

So for example, if max distinct_rank per account id = 2, result would be:

```
account id | val2 | distinct_rank 
___________________________________
3          | d    | 1
3          | e    | 2

This is because account id = 3 has a max distinct_rank of 2.
```

I know how to select where max rank = 2, and I could just do a query that says "select * where account id in a subquery that grabs all with max distinct_rank = 2" but I feel like there might be a better / more efficient way?

Comment: That code (with the dreaded backticks) is invalid for SQL Server. Looks like you are using MySQL, not SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
with cte as
(
select 
`account id`
,`val2`
, dense_rank() over (partition by `account id` order by `val2` desc) as distinct_rank
, count(*) over (partition by `account id` order by `val2` desc) as observation_total
from TABLE1
)

select [account id],val2,distinct_rank from cte
where [account id] in 
    (select [account id] from cte group by [account id] having max(distinct_Rank)=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `max` analytical function:

```
select `account id`, `val2`, distinct_rank, observation_total from
(select distinct 
`account id`
, `val2`
, distinct_rank
, observation_total
, max(distinct_rank) over (partition by `account id`) as max_distinct_rank
from (
select 
`account id`
,`val2`
, dense_rank() over (partition by `account id` order by `val2` desc) as distinct_rank
, count(*) over (partition by `account id` order by `val2` desc) as observation_total
from TABLE1
))
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no current way to filter rows by the result of a windowed function on the same scope as the `SELECT` that originated it.

This means you ***can't*** do the following:

```
SELECT
    WindowResult = DENSE_RANK() OVER (<OverClause>)
FROM
    SomeTable AS T
WHERE
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (<OverClause>) = 1
```

> Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 6  Windowed functions can only
>   appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

The only way to filter this *without changing the function/logic you are currently using* is to wrap this on a CTE or subquery and reference the result, as you mentioned.

```
;WITH Subquery AS
(
    SELECT
        WindowResult = DENSE_RANK() OVER (<OverClause>)
    FROM
        SomeTable AS T
)
SELECT
    S.*
FROM
    Subquery AS S
WHERE
    S.WindowResult = 1
```

You can, however, try to find our a different way to filter out the rows you don't want without a window function and avoid using a subquery. For this we would need your original table sample data and the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [CROSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#l-using-cross-apply) [APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#using-apply) operator:

```
select
  *
from table1 a
cross apply(
  select count(distinct val2) dist_qnt
  from table1 b where b.[account id] = a.[account id]
) ca
where ca.dist_qnt = 2;
```

Or use the method from this [post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/how-to-distinct-count-with-windows-functions-i-e-over-and-partition-by).

```
select *
from (
  select
    *,
    dense_rank() over(
      partition by [account id] order by val2
    ) +
    dense_rank() over(
      partition by [account id] order by val2 desc
    ) - 1 as dist_qnt
  from table1
) sq
where dist_qnt = 2;
```

But take into account NULL values.

Demo on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/381c2/8).